# how to save the rotated image in the local downloads folder using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have one image and onclick of rotate button the image gets rotate that rotated image onclick of save has to download using javascript or jquery. Please give me the answer how to save the rotated image. In this i am using the js and the jquery

Code for the rotating image

```js
var angle = 0,
  img = document.getElementById('id');
document.getElementById('rotatedown').onclick = function() {
  // $('.cropper-bg').css('display','none')
  angle = (angle + 270) % 360;
  img.className = "rotate" + angle;
  imgRotate = document.getElementById('id').src;
  // cropper = new Cropper(imgRotate);
  $('.saverotatedown').css('display', 'block')
  $('.saverotateright').css('display', 'none')
  $('.saverotateup').css('display', 'none')
  $('.saverotateleft').css('display', 'none')
  let save = document.querySelector(".saverotatedown")
  save.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = imgRotate;
    a.download = 'imaged.png';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
  });
  console.log(img.className, imgRotate);
}
```

```html
<title>Image upload</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://skillrary.com/uploads/images/fav-sr-64x64-logo.png" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/0.8.1/cropper.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font- 
    awesome.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous" rel="preconnect" defer/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/0.8.1/cropper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://skillrary.com/uploads/images/f-sr-logo-195-50.png" id="id" /> 
<button id="rotatedown" class="rotateImgDiv"><i class="fa fa-undo" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
Rotate</button> 
<button class="btn saverotatedown" style="display: none">Save down</button>
```

Comment: have you tried localstorage?

Comment: No, But the image is getting downloaded but not the rotated one

Answer (score 0):

The requested image is `https://skillrary.com/uploads/images/f-sr-logo-195-50.png`, so when the user (through the browser) wants to save the manipulated image, it still requests the original image instead.

Instead of manipulating the element directly and with CSS, try creating a new `Image` object, manipulate that and serve it on a canvas element through JavaScript. This image can be downloaded in the manipulated state.

In your HTML add:

```
<div id="canvas"></div>
```

Then in your Javascript:

```
var img = new Image(); // Create new image

// Create a canvas element that will serve as where your image will be drawn.
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Set the source of Image Object. 
img.src = 'https://skillrary.com/uploads/images/f-sr-logo-195-50.png';

// Perform your image manipulation here and finish it off with a drawImage();
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

More info can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas).